# What is the relationship between stress granules and circular RNAs?

Tags: proteins, molecular-genetics, rna, neurology, stress

I have read that [circRNAs act as sponges for miRNAs](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/30259371/) and that [stress granules help reduce chronic cellular stress and they are composed of proteins and RNAs](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4256948/). I'm interested in the relationship between these two phenomena in Alzheimer's disease. [They both seem to be important to mark the disease and there is possible evidence of circRNAs in stress granules](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5732946/).

Is there a specific relation between the two? I would like to know even if it doesn't actually relate to the disease or not.

Comment: Can you cite/link the references that you have read that state this?

Comment: Stress Granules source : https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4256948/

Comment: Circular RNAs source: https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/30259371/

Comment: I've added these citations as links, as well as a potentially useful citation for the relationship to Alzheimer's.

Comment: Thanks! That link is pretty useful.